# Automatically set up new Digital Ocean server for Laravel app

Tags: laravel, configuration

I know that https://forge.laravel.com/auth/register is available for $12/month*, but I'd like to understand how to accomplish the same thing myself.

What I assume is possible (and what I'm looking for): **I create a server that has only Ubuntu 18.04.3 installed and nothing else, and I upload a script that installs all the appropriate software and sets up MySQL with the correct passwords, etc (without manual intervention).**

I've tried [Laradock](https://laradock.io) and had tons of problems with Docker and don't want to do that anymore.

I see that https://cloud.digitalocean.com/droplets/new lets me create a [LEMP droplet](https://cloud.digitalocean.com/marketplace/5ba19755c472e4189b34e04e) (Ubuntu, Nginx, MySQL, PHP-FPM) with one click. But it lacks Redis, and its versions are outdated (e.g. PHP 7.2).

I've heard people mention Chef (maybe [this?](https://www.chef.io/)), but that seems to be more complicated than what I'm imagining.

Unfortunately I'm not even sure how to search for what I'm trying to do (or how to tag this question); is this called "server provisioning"? I've been searching phrases like "automatic install script redis mysql server for laravel".

Thanks in advance for pointing me in the right direction.

<sub>* I also just found https://getcleaver.com/ and https://runcloud.io/server-management, which each look like Forge + Envoyer (and RunCloud offers a free plan).</sub>

Answer (score 1):

It is called server provisioning and [Chef](https://www.chef.io/) would be a good fit for this, check out [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) too - another thing you could do is setup the server yourself and create an image from that server and then base your new servers out of that image, that way you'll have all your services installed from the start.

Comment: I wonder what you think about [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58348934/automatically-set-up-new-digital-ocean-server-for-laravel-app#comment103053593_58349218) too. Thanks!

Comment: I think the easiest thing you can do is either grab a pre-made server image or made your own and base all your installs out of that one.

Server provisioning is normally a bit more complicated than just giving you a script to run that will work for Laravel since the underlying OS isn't the same, even using the same ubuntu version from different cloud providers will have small changes and differences between them.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job or something like [Puppet](https://puppet.com/) (or Chef/Ansible), however [Laravel Envoy](https://laravel.com/docs/master/envoy) may be another tool to look at if you haven't already for the second part of your problem.

I highly recommend Heroku (or similar service), as this is all done out of the box, and has a ton of other great features that make developing a pipeline a breeze.

Comment: Added a footnote to my question. I've heard of Puppet, Chef, Heroku, and now Ansible. What is really blowing my mind is that I haven't found something as simple as running something like [this](https://github.com/laravel/settler/blob/master/scripts/provision.sh). Thoughts about https://github.com/dopyoman/laravel-server/issues/2 ? The Puppet, Chef, Heroku, and Ansible sites look so daunting and not inviting for beginners who are running one or two small sites. Thanks.